# Web Assembly drawing gray canvas

Tags: string, go, random, colors, webassembly

I'm using Go and compiling it to web assembly.

I'm trying to render a bunch of rectangles next to eachother with a random colour, but they keep rendering as just gray.

My render function looks something like this:

```
 for row,_ := range rows {
    for col,_ := range row {
        ctx.Set("fillStyle", fmt.Sprintf("#%06x", rand.Int()))
        ctx.Call("fillRect", 20, 20 + (col * width), maxHeight - (row*height))
    }
 }
```

With which it renders a big block (all rectangles are next to eachother) but just all in gray, instead of doing them in different colours.

Is this enough code in the example to help further? If not I can post it to a gist, as I'm new to WASM I'm unsure which parts could really be relevant - but those 2 functions are the only ones doing something with rendering as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use this expression to construct the fill style:

```
fmt.Sprintf("#%06x", rand.Int())
```

[`rand.Int()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Int) returns a non-negative pseudo-random `int`. Size of `int` is 64 bits if `GOOS=js` and `GOARCH=wasm`. What this means is that the random `int` number will be random 8 bytes (first bit being always 0 due to being non-negative).

If you format such a number with the `%06x` verb, like almost all the time it will be more than just 6 hex digits. The width `6` means to be *at least* 6, and the flag `0` means to pad with zeros if less. But if it's longer, it is not truncated.

And if you set an invalid color to [`canvas.fillStyle`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillstyle.asp), it will disregard it and the last set valid fill style will remain active. And I'm guessing it was a gray color you used before the loop.

Fix is easy, just make sure the random number has no more than 3 bytes, or in other words, 6 hex digits. Use a simple bitmask:

```
ctx.Set("fillStyle", fmt.Sprintf("#%06x", rand.Int()&0xffffff))
```

Or use [`rand.Intn()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Intn) instead of `rand.Int()`:

```
ctx.Set("fillStyle", fmt.Sprintf("#%06x", rand.Int(0x1000000)))
```

Also [`context.fillRect()`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillrect.asp) expects 4 arguments: `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`, so it should be something like this:

```
ctx.Call("fillRect", 20+(col*width), maxHeight-(row*height), width, height)
```

Comment: Mystery solved! Thank you, the explanation that changing GOOS also changes the size of int is really helpful. I hadn't figured that out yet. :)

Comment: @DylanMeeus Also `context.fillRect()` requires 4 arguments (x, y, width, height), I assume you used 4 in your code, right?

Comment: I did, but I made an error writing the example here :) good catch

Comment: Lol I'm going to blame being tired on this. I made an edit to the wrong one :)